# Build the ecologically most sustainable travel route in Europe oneself

Tags: international-travel, public-transport, europe

I'd like to find the ecologically most sustainable travel route with classic public transport (bus, train, ship, plane) within Europe by myself without a travel agency. Is there a webpage to build a travel route with classic public transport from one European town to another European town - e.g. from Neapel to Dublin - with most sustainability as the main criteria?

There are several webpages which address part of this question. They either find the fastest or the cheapest travel route which is, unfortunately, not green enough (e.g. [Google](https://www.google.com) itself or [Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net)). Otherwise, they give tips about the choice of economical vehicles (e.g. [European Climate Pact](https://europa.eu/climate-pact/about/priority-topics/green-transport_en)) or green accommodations (e.g. [Green Pearls](https://www.greenpearls.com/hotels/f/locations/europe/)). Unfortunately, none of them combines finding travel routes with sustainability as a criteria.

Comment: Finding the "most" may be difficult. But it is relatively straightforward to find rail (and sometimes bus) planning for (at least western) Europe (e.g. https://www.eurail.com/en/plan-your-trip/eurail-timetable for rail, omio and trainline for bus/rail). EU rail also has a map of major rail links that can help you plan (https://www.eurail.com/content/dam/pdfs/eurail/Eurail-Map-2021.pdf). Ireland and UK pose additional complications, but the options for cross-strait travel are also limited.

Comment: [ViaMichelin](https://www.viamichelin.com/) will provide you with an estimate of CO2 emissions for various types of car and various routes.  But it's not clear to me that it takes into account emissions from any ferries that you might use, and it doesn't compare the emissions to those incurred by train, bus, or plane for the same distance.

Comment: Also, in the US, the Google Maps phone app will [estimate the lowest-emissions route](https://techcrunch.com/2021/10/06/google-maps-launches-eco-friendly-routing-in-the-u-s/) and present it as an option.  (As far as I can tell, this feature is only available on the phone app, not on the Google Maps website.) They plan to roll this feature out in Europe "in 2022" according to that article.

Comment: There is no clear definition of 'most sustainable', so there can hardly be a correct answer. You could _walk_, which produces very little emissions. If you don't want to walk, you are not looking for the 'most sustainable' but for the 'most sustainable within some parameters I didn't mention', which no website can answer for you.

Comment: Crossing the English Channel by (electric) train is possibly the practical way. The Irish Sea isn't so easy but as @Aganju remarked, you might consider finding a sailboat somehow.

Comment: Have you looked at [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/)?  Rome2Rio integrates different public transportation providers into its routes.

Comment: I would recommend [Eurovelo](https://en.eurovelo.com/), but bicycle is not in the OP's list of transportation means.

Comment: Don't use planes :-) Besides that, sticking to trains where available and taking buses where not is generally speaking most likely the best approach.